# Random but each should appear only once

Tags: java, random

I'm making an app with android studio.

I wanted to make a "Random" function. This is what it looks like in java:

```
final String[] lesquestions = {"random1", "random2", "random3"};
b_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int rando_questions = (int) (Math.random() * 3);

        question.setText(lesquestions[rando_questions]);
    }
});
```

It works fine, but I want that when a string appears, it is taken out of the list, so it doesn't appear twice.

Edit: more precisely: the randoms are questions, and i want that the questions only appear once, no repetitions.

Comment: What is supposed to happen after all of the strings have been displayed?

Comment: Just "the game is over".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use Java list instead of array, so it's gonna be much more comfortable to manage it, and then do something like this:

```
final List<String> lesquestions = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("random1", "random2", "random3"));

b_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int rando_questions = (int) (Math.random() * lesquestions.size());

        question.setText(lesquestions.remove(rando_questions));

    }
});
```

Comment: The next button click and you might get IndexOutofBoundsException.

Comment: @Arnaud yeah, exactly, but question was not about it, so, but I've edited my answer)

Comment: Now, you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` everytime

Comment: @DudeCoder yeah, I guess you're right, not every time, but still. Fixed.

Comment: @DudeCoder it's kinda hard to right a 100% correct answer without actual writing and testing the code))

Comment: @DudeCoder Math.random() generates double number from 0 to 1.

Comment: @20fps... Yes i know

Comment: Or use a queue.

Comment: @DudeCoder you was wrong about IndexOutOfBounds as far as 1 is never generated

Comment: I've tested all the answer posted here, the problem is the same for all: the text doesn't show up. I press the b_question, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
final List<String> lesquestions = newArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(lesquestions, "random1", "random2", "random3");

b_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    Random random = new Random();    

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (lesquestions.isEmpty()) {
            question.setText("Fini");
            return;
        }
        int questionIndex = random.nextInt(lesquestions.size());
        question.setText(lesquestions.remove(questionIndex));   
    }
});
```

To pick a new, random question, one can remove the randomly picked item, but not from a fixed size array, but a collection, a `Set<String>` if the questions must be unique,
or a `List<String>` if you would like the possibility of a repeated question.

- `Arrays.asList` would convert an array / enumeration of strings to a List, backed by that array, so **fixed** size. So that cannot be used when one wants removal.
- Creating a Random is a bit more circumstantial than `Math.random` but `nextInt(int n)` is much more clear: a value 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1.
- `List.remove` returns the removed element, so it works as a getter at the same time.
- At one time no questions remain.

Bon chance.

Comment: yeah, I guess your answer is the most complicated one, but I don't see any reason to create new Random instance every time as far as we can just use Math.random()

Comment: I've tested all the answer posted here, the problem is the same for all: the text doesn't show up. I press the b_question, but nothing changes.

Comment: That requries debugging, `b_question.setClickable(true);` maybe, whether the `onClick` is called, `question` visible and large enough.